# How do I get git to give me all revisions of a single file

Tags: git, git-rev-list

I'm trying to figure out the last time a file had a certain string in it

I found this:

```
git rev-list --all | xargs git grep <search str> | grep <file name>
```

But that runs git grep against every single file that's ever been modified, then throws out all matches that aren't in the file of interest

So, it works, but it's really slow

How do I tell git rev-list to only give me revisions for a specified file?

I tried

```
git rev-list --all path/to/file.py
```

And it just gave me every file.  So I tried each of these

```
git rev-list path/to/file.py
git rev-list -- path/to/file.py
```

But for both git returned help text

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out the last time a file had a certain string in it

```
git log --oneline --no-merges -p -S 'that string' -- that/file
```

or if you want to know all the places that deletion was merged, too

```
git log --oneline -m -p -S 'that string' -- that/file
```

and check the patches for whether the text was deleted or added.

---

`git rev-list` doesn't default to the `HEAD` commit, you have to specify exactly where to start, that's why your later tries were failing.

---

From comments, you're not just looking for complete removal of a string from a file, you're looking for changes removing that string from particular places in a file.  For those, use `-G` not `-S`. `-G` looks for that pattern appearing in diffs where `-S` ignores diffs that don't change the total number of occurrences -- `-S` does what you asked for, but not what you want.

Comment: git log --oneline -m -p -S 'Greg' -- path/to/file.py ==> returns nothing.  Since my name is in the comment for most functions in the file, something is failing

Comment: Ah. use `-G` instead of `-S` then, `-S` is looking for changes in the total number of occurrences of that string in a file, `-G` looks for diffs on lines containing that string.